# wrap start delay around jquery animate functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".left").animate({left:"-50%"},4000);
$(".center").animate({right:"-50%"},8000);
$(".right").animate({right:"-50%"},4000);
```

I would like to simply delay start all of my animations above, by wrapping a delay function around them, keeping the same animate code, just start after about `1100);`

Comment: can't you use `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a call to [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)!

Try `$(".left").delay(2000).animate({left: "-50%"}, 4000);` to insert a delay of 2 seconds, for example.

Comment: Noting that you'd have to add .delay() to all three lines.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".left").animate({
        left: "0%"
      }, 4000);
      $(".center").animate({
        right: "0%"
      }, 8000);
      $(".right").animate({
        right: "0%"
      }, 4000);
    }, 1100);
  });
})
```

```css
body {
 position: relative;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="center"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't think adding a ready handler, a click handler, CSS, etc. is overkill when the question just asked for a way to delay execution of something? (And for some reason you even changed what the animations are doing?)

Comment: Just only for run snippet